# manage.py runserver failed with messgae "Unknown command: 'runserver'"

Tags: python, django

I'm running a django project in docker container, when I run `python manage.py runserver` or `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` it works, but when I run `python manage.py runserver --settings=configs.local_default` which is what I actually need gets error message:

```
Unknown command: 'runserver'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

The running django version is 1.3.1

Comment: Try using django-admin.py syncdb --settings=configs.local_default

Comment: Classic Django 1.3. Consider to upgrade your django to 1.4 (LTS) at least.... or Django 1.8 (LTS) recommended.

Comment: @VaibhavMule Seems logical,  I'll try this as soon as docker rebuild is finished.

Comment: I do even suggest to upgrade to 1.4 at least there is not any docs related 1.3 in on Django Project website.

Comment: @Yeo It's a history problem, we are trying to move the project app by app.

Answer (score 0):

The issue it probably that you're working with Django 1.3 which is poorly documented and pretty buggy. Just use one of the more recent versions.
Both 1.7 and 1.8 are really good. The tutorials on the Django website are more than enough to catch you up on the changes and it's much more efficient than working with 1.3. The entire server structure is much more organized and hence way easier to debug especially when working with multiple apps. The plug-n-play aspect makes it particularly easy.
It won't be hard to port your code either.